# JQGrid-Treegrid : Remove icon from leaf nodes

Tags: jqgrid

I am using JQGrid treegrid. I want to remove icon from the leaf node (The default icon for JQGrid-Treegrid leaf node looks like a small radio  button and my manager didn't like it)

I used below options to remove the icon image in the leaf nodes but no success

```
treeIcons: { leaf: 'nonexistingstyle' }
treeIcons: { leaf: '' }
treeIcons: { leaf: null }
```

none of the above works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jquery UI empty icon:

```
treeIcons: { leaf: 'ui-icon-blank' }
```